# How to make sure the distribution file for maven project have name that doesn't relate to a certain version, instead always contain the latest

Tags: java, maven, build, gitlab, pom.xml

I'm currently working on a Maven project and I want to create a fat jar. when I'm doing a remote build, the name of the jar automatically gets transformed to some numbers, which I don't want since I would have to update my other project to use the latest JAR.

Currently my pom.xml has this:

```
<artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
<groupId>a.b.c.d</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

When I do remote build, 1.0-SNAPSHOT gets transformed into 000-feature-**7654321** (this number gets changed every time I make a new commit)

Due to this, the generated jar file looks like myProject-000-feature-7654321.jar but I want it to be something like
myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar which will always contain the latest changes.

Comment: Sounds like your CI changes/configures the version number during the build.

Comment: yep, found the issue. it was because of gitlab-ci.yml file. thanks Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your remote build changes the version before or during the build.

Look at the gitlab build script to figure out what happens there.

Comment: during the build. in the logs it says 1.0-SNAPSHOT is transformed to 000-features-7654321

Comment: This is probably done by your gitlab-ci build script. But we cannot tell if you do not know it.

Comment: thanks, that was really useful. so, In the gtilab-ci.yml, I used something like version = {SEVER_VERSION}, I changed it to version =  {VERSION} .now, it's working as I want.